# Is there a "generic" iterator type to be used in C++ for function parameters?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a C++ class that contains a `std::list` as member. Now I want to add a method that can be used to insert values of another container into that list. Something like this:

```
template<class factType>
class BeliefSet
{
    std::list<factType> m_List;
    void SetFacts(??? IterBegin, ??? IterEnd)
    {
        m_List.insert(m_List.end(), IterBegin, IterEnd);
    }
};
```

Now my question is: What do I have to replace `???` with, so that it can take the iterator of any (or at least most common) `std` containers, like `list`, `vector`, etc.? I tried it with `std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, factType>`, but that didn't seem to work.

Note that this should also work with a copy constructor, like this:

```
const std::list<factType>& GetFacts() const
{
    return m_List;
}

// Copy constructor.
explicit BeliefSet(const BeliefSet& Other)
{
    auto facts = Other.GetFacts();
    SetFacts(facts.begin(), facts.end());
}
```

Comment: Template the method so it accepts arbitrary inputs, let `m_list.insert` more complicated template deduction verify it's an iterator?

Comment: There is an [std::iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator), you could probably create your own iterator class from that?

Comment: Why not use a template and name the parameter `InputIterator`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make `SetFacts` be a template.  Normally this would be a disadvantage, because it means the method has to be inline.  However, as `BeliefSet` is already a class template, that isn't a problem.

```
template<class factType>
class BeliefSet
{
    std::list<factType> m_List;

    template <class It>
    void SetFacts(It IterBegin, It IterEnd)
    {
        m_List.insert(m_List.end(), IterBegin, IterEnd);
    }
};
```

If you call `SetFacts` with something that isn't an iterator, you'll get error messages out of `list::insert`.  If you are really lucky, you may be able to understand them!

Note that I pass the iterators by value (rather than const reference) - that is because one normally expects iterators to be cheap to copy.

Comment: Maybe I'm just used to generics from other languages, but is there no way to specify `Iterator<factType>`?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq No.  `It` could easily be `factType const *`.  There is no run-time polymorphism amongst iterators.

Answer (score 2):

Use `iterator_tag`.

```
template<class factType>
class BeliefSet
{

    std::list<factType> m_List;
    template <typename Iter>
    void SetFacts(Iter IterBegin, Iter IterEnd)
    {
        SetFacts_Impl(IterBegin, IterEnd, 
         typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::iterator_category());
    }
private:
    template <typename Iter>
    void SetFacts_Impl(Iter IterBegin, Iter IterEnd, std:: bidirectional_iterator_tag )
    {
        std::copy( IterBegin, IterEnd, std::back_inserter( m_List ) );
    }
};
```

This makes sure that it will take any iterator that *atleast* follows the requirements set by `bidirectional iterator`. So will cover both `list` and `vector`

Comment: `list` and `vector` only need a input iterator for construction.

Comment: What does this gain you over calling `m_List.insert` directly in `SetFacts`?

Comment: @MartinBonner Nothing. I just preferred it this way.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, that will give a wider contract.

Answer (score 2):

```
template <class Iter>
void SetFacts(Iter first, Iter last)
    {
        m_List.insert(m_List.end(), first, last);
    }
```

I also changed the names of the arguments to the usual idiom.